# Configuring web.config in WiX

Tags: wix, web-config

I have a MSI which I want to configure the bindings in a web.config. It is a standard web config and I want to change the value of **security mode** and **transport clientCredentialType**

**Snippet of the web.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
     <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServerBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="8388608" maxBufferPoolSize="1048576" >
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="7000000" maxArrayLength="10000000" maxBytesPerRead="7000000" maxNameTableCharCount="7000000"  />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**And the part in Configuration in wix**

```
 <util:XmlFile Id="ServerBindingConfiguration" File="[#BioBroker.Web.config]" Action="setValue" Value="[SECURITYMODE]" ElementPath="/configuration/system.serviceModel/bindings/wsHttpBinding/binding[\[]@name='ServerBinding']/security" Sequence="1"/>
```

How can I change the **security mode** tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not specified the "Name" attribute within the XMlFile element.

> Name  String  Name of XML node to set/add to the specified element. Not
>   setting this attribute causes the element's text value to be set.
>   Otherwise this specified the attribute name that is set.
>
> add Name = "mode"